# Listing named dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, naming

Let two dataframes be built by

```
df1<-data.frame(1,2)
df2<-data.frame(3,4)
```

and listed by

```
list<-list(df1,df2)
```

Then, the dataframes' names are not getting imported into the list. Yet, their names appear if the code is changed to

```
list<-list(df1=df1,df2=df2)
```

However, as I build lists consisting of hundreds of dataframes (imported from Quandl) this means a lot of additional typing. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mget` finds the objects given as a character vector in it's first argument and returns a named list. You can either supply a character vector of the object names you want, or use `ls()` to use a *regular expression* to select the objects you want from the *`Global Environment`* (by default, you can specify other environments for `mget` to look for objects in):

```
mget(c("df1","df2"))
#$df1
#  X1 X2
#1  1  2

#$df2
#  X3 X4
#1  3  4
```

The use of a *regular expression* seems well suited to your case where you have hundreds of `data.frames`...

```
mget( ls( pattern = "df[0-9]+" ) )
#$df1
#  X1 X2
#1  1  2

#$df2
#  X3 X4
#1  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that works well on long lists.

```
> q <- quote(list(df1, df2))
> setNames(eval(q), as.character(q[-1]))
# $df1
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  2
#
# $df2
#   X3 X4
# 1  3  4
```

`q` is an unevaluated expression.  When we call `eval` on it, it gets evaluated and we can turn the expression into a character vector to get the names. `setNames` is nice for applying names to a list, as it returns the named list as the result.

```
> q
# list(df1, df2)
> as.character(q)
# [1] "list" "df1"  "df2"
```